# Tradingview PineScript ADR Range for Daytrading

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, indicator

i try to code an indicator, which takes the ADR of predefined days and plot it inside cash session (9:30-16:00) on my chart 1m 5m 15m 1h or whatever is smaller then 1d. It should plot upper and lower band which will be "consumed" by the realtime chart. So if the price is moving up/down the ADR-margin gets lower. If the movement was bigger then the ADR, then the plot gets red.You can see a screenshot of exactly what i want to recreate. My knowledge with pinescript is low, thats why i try to find here some help.

This screenshots are from a video and the showed indicator is unfortunately not released, i tried to contact this guy without success...

[ADR Check Indicator: Price is inside the ADR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ckn.png)

[ADR Check Indicator: passed the ADR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ6Qv.png)